# Merging multiple attachments of a record into a single pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, merge

Is it possible to merge multiple attachments of a record into a single pdf using javascript or Jquery. Has anyone tried this kind of scnario. If yes, please guide me towards the solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best answer is that Salesforce is unfortunately not well suited to arbitrary PDF generation. Visualforce's PDF functions are rather crude. Most of the built-in facilities fail because they do not allow for font management or detailed layouts. Even headless Chrome solutions are not quite perfect.

The best recommendation for you is to search the AppExchange for a solution. Be prepared to not waste time looking for a solution that does not exist.

My solution to this problem was to write a separate app server in Go that is commanded via REST to read an object (or set of objects) from the database and spit out an HTML5 DOM that you can map onto a Go or Twig template. Once you have an HTML5 version of your final render, then you can use a service like PDFCrowd to make a pixel-perfect PDF in whatever font or color you want. My render app server posts the PDF back into the database as a Salesforce File.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to combine PDFs with javascript or jquery.

You can try this with visualforce.

[Combine multiple PDF's together and attach them in a mail?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50438/combine-multiple-pdfs-together-and-attach-them-in-a-mail)